# Remove data from binary search tree pointed to by pointer of root

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, treenode

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to remove data from a BST using a double pointer and then changing the root if needed. This is what I am trying but when I test it it removes numbers that should not be removed...any idea on what is flawed?

EDIT: Below is my new code after the answer...

```
    int removeBST(struct TreeNode** rootRef, int data)
    {

      while (*rootRef && (*rootRef)->data != data)
      {

         if ((*rootRef)->data > data)
         {

             rootRef = &(*rootRef)->left;
         }
         else if ((*rootRef)->data < data)
         {
              rootRef = &(*rootRef)->right;
         }
     }

    if (*rootRef)
    {
        struct TreeNode *tmp = *rootRef;
        if (rootRef->left == NULL && rootRef->right == NULL) // no children
        {
        free(tmp);
        }
        else if (rootRef->left->left == NULL && rootRef->right->right == NULL) // one child
{
  rootRef = rootRef->left;
}
else
{
  rootRef = inOrderSuccessor(rootRef);
  removeBST(**rootRef, data);
}

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;  

}
```

Comment: `*rootRef = tmp->left;` you do keep the left pointer, but the ->right pointer will be orphanased, including the complete right subtree.

Comment: You can google for pseudocode, for this function. Currently you have maybe 15% of delete node logic. You need pointer to parent of the node you want to delete, and when you delete, you have 3 use cases. 1. Node to be deleted is a leaf 2. Node to be deleted has one child 3. Node to be delted has two children. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12254018/2549281)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the line `*rootRef = tmp->left;`.

This line attempts to delete the node `rootRef`. What it actually does is simply replaces the node with its left child, which is correct if `rootRef` *only has a left child*. If it has a right childe, however, it will become an *orphan*.

What you need to do is handle the deletion properly, as follows:

1. If `rootRef` has **no children**, i.e., `rootRef->left == NULL && rootRef->right == NULL`,
   simply remove the node.
2. If `rootRef` has **only one child**, replace `rootRef` with that child.
3. If `rootRef` has **two children**, replace the value of `rootRef` with its [in-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) successor, and then delete that node *recursively*, until you reach case 1 or 2.

[An example on removing a node from a BST](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal).

Your code must look something similar to this:

```
int removeBST(struct TreeNode** rootRef, int data) {
    while (*rootRef && (*rootRef)->data != data) {
        ...
    }


    struct TreeNode* prootRef = *rootRef;
    if (prootRef) {
        if(prootRef->left && prootRef->right) // Both children exist
            // Find its in-order successor
            ...
        }
        else if(prootRef->left) { // Only left child exists
           // Replace rootRef by its left child
           ...
        }
        else if(prootRef->right) { // Only right child exists
           // Replace rootRef by its right child
           ...
        }
        else { // rootRef is a leaf node
           // Delete rootRef
           ...
        }

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: So I should do some if statements after *rootRef = tmp->left;?

Comment: That statement is incorrect. You need to implement the deletion algorithm, by handling those 3 cases independently.

Comment: Okay so I did that and something is still wrong...I'm pretty sure it has to do with the two child case but I don't know how to recursively check for the children of the child...

Comment: Help please! I am very stuck on this

Comment: How does `(rootRef->left->left == NULL && rootRef->right->right == NULL)` mean that `rootRef` has only 1 child?

Comment: Here's a sample implementation in C for [deleting a node in a BST](http://geeksquiz.com/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/).

Comment: That's helpful but I still don't know how to handle my situation where I am taking in a pointer to a pointer